# Reproducing the Table 3.2 from the Elements of Statistical Learning

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

I was able to reproduce table 3.1 from ESL. However, when I tried to reproduce table 3.2, my estimated coefficients were way off (shown below):

```
         [,1]
 [1,]  0.4292
 [2,]  0.5765
 [3,]  0.6140
 [4,] -0.0190
 [5,]  0.1448
 [6,]  0.7372
 [7,] -0.2063
 [8,] -0.0295
 [9,]  0.0095
```

The results from table 3.2 in ESL are as follow: 
[image]

I have attached my code here:

```
res <- read.table("prostate.data", sep = "")
fix(res)
XTraining = subset(res, train)
XTesting = subset(res, train == FALSE)


nrow = dim( XTraining )[1]
p = dim( XTraining )[2] - 1 # the last column is the response 

D = XTraining[,1:p-1] # get the predictor data

# This gives the raw data for Table 3.1 from the book:
# 
print(cor(D),digts=3)

library(xtable)
xtable( cor(D), caption="Duplication of the values from Table 3.1 from the book", digits=3 )

#
# Duplicate Table 3.2 from the book 
#

# Append a column of ones:
# 
Dp = cbind( matrix(1,nrow,1), as.matrix( D ) )

lpsa = XTraining[,p]

library(MASS)

betaHat = ginv( t(Dp) %*% Dp ) %*% t(Dp) %*% as.matrix(lpsa)

# this is basically the first column in Table 3.2:
#
print('first column: beta estimates')
print(betaHat,digits=2)
```

Does anyone have similar issues ? I would like to know what went wrong with my output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you have not scaled the data as described in the information file:

http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/datasets/prostate.info.txt

> The features must first be scaled to have mean zero and  variance 96 (=n)
>   before the analyses in Tables 3.1 and beyond.  That is, if x is the  96 by 8 matrix
>   of features, we compute xp <- scale(x,TRUE,TRUE)

This gives the correct answer:

```
X <- read.table("prostate.data", sep = "")
train <- X[,10]
y <- X[,9]
X <- X[,-(9:10)]

X.scaled <- scale(X,TRUE,TRUE)

betaHat <- lm(y[train]~X.scaled[train,])$coef
print(betaHat)

         (Intercept)  X.scaled[train, ]lcavol X.scaled[train, ]lweight     X.scaled[train, ]age    X.scaled[train, ]lbph 
          2.46493292               0.67952814               0.26305307              -0.14146483               0.21014656 
X.scaled[train, ]svi     X.scaled[train, ]lcp X.scaled[train, ]gleason   X.scaled[train, ]pgg45 
          0.30520060              -0.28849277              -0.02130504               0.26695576
```

Comment: +1, my mistake was scaling y as well.